# Drag&Drop files into winform app does not work

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, .net-4.5

I would like to add drag&drop feature to my winform app developed in .Net 4.5 by using C#.
I try the first solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68598/how-do-i-drag-and-drop-files-into-a-c-sharp-application) but it did not works.

I downloaded the [example project](http://www.codeproject.com/script/articles/download.aspx?file=/KB/cs/dragdrop/dragdrop.zip&rp=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3598/Drag-and-Drop-files-from-Windows-Explorer-to-Windo) from codeproject. when I compile and run the example code in example solution, it works. However when I copy the example code in my project again it does not work!

Even no events triggered about drag&drop!

The codeproject example compiled in .Net 2, does it matter?

Is there any one who implements drag&drop file into winform app by using .Net 4.5?
Can you help me?

Comment: [Check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14557077/drag-and-drop-files-and-saving-it-using-mvc) i have asked and its answer if it could help you a bit

Comment: ***Copy & paste*** without caring about `event handler register` would be your problem.

Comment: Change target framework of projects in codeproject.com in order to debug them.

Answer (score 0):

After I wrote the question, I discover a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123772/why-is-dragdrop-not-working-under-vs2010) which says that it is about user role elevation.
When I compile my code and it from compiled exe it works. But still I did not debugging it!