# Drag Drop won't work in Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drag-and-drop

Drag drop event work fine on Windows 7 or old Operating systems.
But won't work on Windows 8.
How to fix?

```
private void listBox1_DragEnter(objectsender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
}

private void listBox1_MouseDown(objectsender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  Point sonnokta = new Point(e.X,e.Y);
  int item_index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(sonnokta);
  if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
  {
    listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.Items[item_index],DragDropEffects.All);
  }
}

private void listBox2_DragOver(objectsender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.KeyState == 1)
  {
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
  }
}

private void listBox2_DragDrop(objectsender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  listBox2.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
}
```

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: not gives error, not work drop event.

Comment: Posted code works (I'm on Windows 8.1).  Make sure ListBox2 has AllowDrop = True.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is DragDrop not working under VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123772/why-is-dragdrop-not-working-under-vs2010)