# Why won't my DragDrop handlers fire?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

Created a WinForm app, set AllowDrop property on the form to true, wired up the drag handlers (enter, exit, over and drop) and they weren't firing.  Why not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is DragDrop not working under VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123772/why-is-dragdrop-not-working-under-vs2010)

Answer (score 0):

I always launch visual studio from a shortcut that runs it as Administrator (because I often do socket stuff that requires admin rights).  But my windows explorer shell is not executing as admin, so it disallows the drop due to permissions.

Relaunching VS without admin permissions fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm posting this because this is the second time I've run into this problem, and the second time I've figured out the answer.  I don't want to have to figure it out again.  Stupid long-term memory.